# How to replace list of chars from the string

Tags: python

I have a search string If the character inside the search matches  then replace with None

```
sear = '!%'
special_characters = ['!', '"', '#', '$', '%','(',')']
for remove_char in special_characters:
   search_value = re.sub(remove_char, '', sear)
```

My out got error

Expected out is None

```
sear = 'ABC!%DEF'
Expected is 'ABCDEF'
```

```
sear = 'ABC,DEF'
Expected is 'ABC,DEF'
```

Comment: When I execute it with print(sear) after, I receive '!%'. Are you sure about the output ?

Comment: error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0

Comment: I think he wanted to print the `search_value` instead of `sear`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do a list comprehension and `''.join`:

```
sear = '!%'
special_characters = ['!', '"', '#', '$', '%']
sear = ''.join([i for i in sear if i not in special_characters])
print(sear)
```

This code iterates the string by characters, and see if the character is not in the `special_characters` list, if it's not, it keeps it, if it is, it removes, but that only gives us a list of strings, so we need `''.join` to change it into a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a regex character class out of your special characters and then use a regex substitution to do the replacements. For longer strings or larger lists of special characters, you should find this runs 2-3x faster than the list comprehension solution.

```
import re

special_characters = ['!', '"', '#', '$', '%','(',')']
regex = re.compile('[' + ''.join(f'\{c}' for c in special_characters) + ']')

sear = '!%'
search_value = regex.sub('', sear)
print(search_value)
sear = 'ABC!%DEF'
search_value = regex.sub('', sear)
print(search_value)
sear = 'ABC,DEF'
search_value = regex.sub('', sear)
print(search_value)
```

Output:

```
<blank line>
ABCDEF
ABC,DEF
```

Note I've prefixed all characters in the character class with `\` so that you don't have to worry about using characters such as `-` and `]` which have special meaning within a character class.